# Angular Ionic @ViewChild looses reference

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, viewchild

The problem is simple

I have a reference like this

```
@ViewChild('myElement') myElementVar : SomeClass;
```

And the element I'm refering looks like this

```
<element #myElement *ngIf="someBoolean"></element>
```

And when `someBoolean` goes false, `myElementVar` goes undefined, **I know that** is because `*ngIf` totally removes the element from the DOM and then it looses the reference because it doesn't exist anymore.

**What i want to know is** if is possible to re-assign 
`myElementVar` to `#myElement`
when `someBoolean` goes true again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via using ChangeDetectorRef.

In the following example: you click and activate toggle function and then, the function removes the first line with its reference:

```
<h1 #myElement *ngIf="someBool">Hello World.</h1>
```

Then,
when you toggle again, you re-assign your referenced element.

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-roh6g8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Please note** that you may also do this without ChangeDetectorRef if you still make sure that you have a condition to check whether your reference exists or not and Angular will automatically (internally) handle that for you.